# Two threads writing different fields of same entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following situation.

One business entity (BE) consists of 2 parts provided asynchronously by 2 threads.
Example: our BE has fields id and, A, B, C - all in one table in database. Id is generated by sequence when entity is stored into database. B is unique field, there's constraint on it in database.  Process1 provides fields A and B. Process2  provides fields B and C. So after both processes finish, we should have one row in a table with all columns filled in.

What is the good way to make this work?

What is done now:

In each process we first select all values from table where value in column B is what we now have. (If any - this means the other process already saved it's part). If there's something, it is enriched with the missing column and persisted. If there's nothing - we just persist what we have. But while all this is done, it can occur that the other process finished it's job and when we persist our entity, we get ConstraintViolationException and hibernate marks transaction to rollback. And the missing column is still missing.

Comment: No source code. No clear, specific question. I get spirals reading your question. Please clarify, and demonstrate the problem, at least theoretically.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to decide how you want conflicts to be handled. For this answer the following questions:

If process 1 changes your entity while process 2 is running are the results of 2 still valid? Or should it rerun?

If process 1 updates field B should while process 2 is running should process 2 overwrite it? or just keep the value of process 1?

Of course the questions should also be answered with 1 and 2 interchanged.

If you implement the process in a way that they take the original entity, and produce a new modified + the original entity they startet with, you can have a single queue where all these results get added and a single process applying these changes to your database.

In specific scenarios, simpler approaches might be possible, but this is the approach I would recommend in the very general case you describe in your question.

Answer (score -1):

i would do it this way

- load or create Entity before launching the threads
- launch thread and give it to each
- update it in both threads
- when both finished save to db

Comment: accessing a hibernate entity from two threads is probably not a good idea. It's easy to trigger loading of lazy stuff which would result in concurrent access to the session, which it can't handle properly. Also the two threads mentioned in the question both access field B, creating another mine field.

Comment: sure i didn't thought of lazy loaded collections but this is easy to prevent with eager fetching. property B is not a problem since both threads work on the same entity and B is unique hence B must be the same for both threads. I would even set B before the threads start and use in a Map as key for the threads to find it for updating.